# Angular 1.2.24: Testing directive throws undefined in scope.$digest();

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, karma-runner

I've just installed AngularJS 1.2.24 and I'm trying to test my directive. The code looks like follows:

```
describe('scenarios', function () {

    var scope, compile;

    beforeEach(module("app"));
    beforeEach(module("src/widgets/tt-header/header.html"));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        compile = $compile;
    }));

    function directive() {

        var el = angular.element('<div tt-header />');

        compile(el)(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        return el;
    }

    it('should load the directive', function () {

        var el = directive();

        expect(el).not.toBe(undefined);
    });
});
```

Then, when I run the test I get the following message during execution of **scope.$digest()**:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) tt-header scenarios should load the tt-header directive FAILED
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$browser.$$checkUrlChange()')
            at /Users/alansouza/tt-workspace/tt-app-angular/vendor/angular/angular.js:12502
            at ttHeader (/Users/alansouza/tt-workspace/tt-app-angular/tests/widgets/tt-header/tt-header-specs.js:20)
            at /Users/alansouza/tt-workspace/tt-app-angular/tests/widgets/tt-header/tt-header-specs.js:27
```

It seems to be something related to url changes in the browser. I compared to previous versions and this seems a new code to me.

I tried to revert to my previous working version 1.2.21 and everything works fine.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please post the exact Error message and stack-trace.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with 1.2.24. I downgraded to 1.2.23 and it's working correctly again.

Comment: As requested, I've added the full stack trace...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that was a mismatched version with the Angular mocks. I've updated my **angular-mocks.js** to this one [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngMock) and everything works fine now.

Comment: Had the same problem, updating angular mocks solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Also had this problem while upgrading from angular 1.2.19 to 1.2.24 
Digged half of the internet before finding this :)