# AngularJS: TypeError: undefined is not a function with chained selects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, select, undefined

I have two select boxes, options for one of the boxes are loaded right away, and the second (child) select will get its options from a callback that queries an API. It is not an option to pre-load all possible options because there are 4200 records that would be loaded without the parent's selected value.

When the ng-change event of the parent box fires, a call is made:

```
function CertificateSearchCtrl($q, CPSIAService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.products = [];
    vm.categories = [];

    vm.certficate = {};
    vm.categoryselect = {};
    vm.productselect = {};
```

I can call this via ng-init, or directly in the controller on first load

```
    vm.loadCategories = function() {
        CPSIAService.getCategories().then(function(results){
            vm.categories = results;
        });
    };
```

OR I can call this in the same fashion (ng-init or direct via controller)

```
    vm.findProducts = function(data) {
        CPSIAService.getProductsByCategory(data.id).then(function(results){
                vm.products = results;
        });
    };
   ...
```

But I can't call the two together at all, either through ng-change or direct through controller forcing a category ID into the findProducts() call.

This should, in turn, allow the child select to be populated with the "products" array. The controlling html (which is output via a directive) is this:

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6">
<select ng-model="vm.categoryselect" ng-change="vm.findProducts(vm.categoryselect)" ng-options="categories.category for categories in vm.categories track by categories.id" ng-cloak>
    <option value="">(choose a category)</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="small-12 medium-6">
<select ng-model="vm.productselect" ng-change="vm.loadCertificate(vm.productselect)" ng-show="vm.products.length>0" ng-options="products.description for products in vm.products track by products.sku" ng-cloak>
    <option value="">(select a product)</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Even if I try to load the options for the child select initially (rather than through the ng-change event) - I get the same error.  Here is the Chrome stack trace:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
at render (angular.js:25905)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14280)
at Scope.scopePrototype.$digest (hint.js:1468)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14493)
at Scope.scopePrototype.$apply (hint.js:1478)
at HTMLSelectElement.selectionChanged (angular.js:25657)
at HTMLSelectElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3011)angular.js:11598 (anonymous function)angular.js:8548 $getangular.js:14282 $get.Scope.$digesthint.js:1468 scopePrototype.$digestangular.js:14493 $get.Scope.$applyhint.js:1478 scopePrototype.$applyangular.js:25657 selectionChangedangular.js:3011 eventHandler
```

Here is a sample of the JSON data in question. I've linted/validated it and it is fine.

```
[{"sku":"2004","description":"ADHSVE PAPR BLK BDR8CT-12"},{"sku":"2005","description":"ADHSVE PAPR BLU BDR8CT-12"},{"sku":"2006","description":"ADHSVE PAPR RED BDR8CT-12"},{"sku":"0043630-5987","description":"BORD 50 CS ASST 60 CT-1"},{"sku":"51671","description":"SLFSTK BORDER BLK 2X12-12"},{"sku":"51672","description":"SLFSTK BORDER BLU 2X12-12"},{"sku":"51673","description":"SLFSTK BORDER RED 2X12-12"}]
```

Help!

I have noticed that I can, in fact load my child select options *only if* I don't attempt to make two calls to my service at one time.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding promises?  I thought they resolve with the .then() function, but it errors out when I try to make the second one complete, even though the API call is fine and data does come back as expected (see JSON above)

JQuery does not affect the error - same reproduction with or without jQuery included.

Comment: What AngularJS version are you using?

Comment: 1.3.11.  can reproduce this issue in earlier versions down to <=1.3.5 as well.

Comment: So, `(angular.js:25905)` falls on `.prop('selected', option.selected)`?

Comment: yes, it would appear that way, but I can't pinpoint why

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could try changing to other jQuery versions? Just to mention, `.prop()` was introduced on jQuery 1.6: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I'm running 2.1.1 right now, but I can still reproduce the error when I remove jQuery entirely.

Comment: @Fred, can you repro this in plunker/fiddle?

Comment: Possibly the problem are in your services. Could you share their code with us?

Comment: @Fred, something else is going on that is not in the code you posted.. Here's roughly what you are doing working fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/YeWgog6TRCqeDmtVBaZb?p=preview

Comment: Thanks all - @New Dev -> I can't get this to run in plunkr, but maybe conceptually this will show you what I'm trying to do.  Can provide a live URL upon request as well.  Thanks so much! http://plnkr.co/edit/1ow1c6DOrB83Fos0GZRV

Comment: Seriously: your AngularJS code seems very strange on Plnkr. For example: there are some duplicate variables (try not to declare variables with the same name as its function), and there are some commented code (try not to use the commented deferred variable). These kind of mistakes might cause the undefined error you are facing. Since Plnkr don't work well, we can't help much. Please, if your problem persists, try pasting the services and related code as it is on the environment with error (note that, obviously, you might change sensitive information on your code, if any).

Comment: Have you read either Todd Motto or John Papa's Angular style guides? The code is not strange.  All effort is made not to pollute the $scope, (unlike most examples out there).  I commented out those two lines to show that they *should* come from an API call, to give the most context I can to anyone kind enough to try and help (such as yourself).  
=== Read more about the "why" of this coding approach in angular here ===
Todd Motto's AngularJS Style Guide: https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide

John Papa's AngularJS Style Guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution guys.  In my service, I had this:

```
function CPSIAService($q, Restangular) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var CPSIAService = {};

    CPSIAService.getProductsByCategory = function(params) {
        //original call 
        // var response = Restangular.one('compliance/products/by/category',params);

        var response = Restangular.one('products.json'); //params from category would go here

        response.getList().then(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    CPSIAService.getCategories = function() {
        //original call
        //var response = Restangular.all('compliance/categories/all');

        var response = Restangular.all('categories.json');

        response.getList().then(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return CPSIAService;
}
```

Specifically, notice this at the top of the service:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
```

If I were to make a call to the service after initial page load, the error would occur because I wasn't deferring the promise in the actual function I was calling.  The solution was to go from this:

```
CPSIAService.getProductsByCategory = function(params) {
        var response = Restangular.one('compliance/products/by/category',params);

        response.getList().then(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

to this:

```
CPSIAService.getProductsByCategory = function(params) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();  //defer here because we're calling it from the ng-change event fire
        var response = Restangular.one('compliance/products/by/category',params);

        response.getList().then(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

And now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and solution was to update `angular-mocks.js` to the matching version as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795209/1614973).